# SBCL dynamic-space-size setting ignored in Windows 10

Tags: memory-management, common-lisp, sbcl

Is it possible to increase the sbcl dynamic-space-size beyond the default of 1024 on Windows 10 in version SBCL 2.0.0?

For example, loading from the command prompt with `sbcl --dynamic-space-size 2048` seems to be ignored since `(/ (- sb-vm:dynamic-space-end sb-vm:dynamic-space-start) (expt 1024 2))` still returns 1024, not 2048. Thanks.

Comment: I also use SBCL 2.0.0 on Windows 10, and it seems to work as expected for me. I tried copying and pasting what you gave and I get 2048 as output.

Comment: You're right. The incorrect value is not repeatable this morning. Thank you.